# Python psycopg2 delete records with multiple where condition

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to delete records in a postgres table with 2 where conditions. For this I am using `psycopg2`. Now the values of each condition are stored in a list.

Below is the code snippet:

```
def delete_record(tbl_name,locations,files):
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect('connection string')
        conn.autocommit = True
        curr = conn.cursor()
        ods_tb = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM ods.{};'.format(tbl_name),conn)
        ods_tb_row = ods_tb.shape[0]
        for l in locations:
            for f in files:
                ods_tbl_select = pd.read_sql_query("""SELECT * FROM ods.{} where location='{1}' and filename='{2}';""".format(tbl_name,l,f),conn) 
    #<-- Please check the above line##
                if ods_tbl_select:
                    for l in locations:
                        for f in files:
                            curr.execute("""DELETE  FROM ods.{} where location=%s and filename=%s;""".format(tbl_name), (l,f,) ) 
    #<-- Also please check the above line. Is this a valid way of operation on DB##                        
                            row_deleted = curr.rowcount
                            conn.commit()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        msg = str(error)
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()
    return row_deleted,ods_tb_row,msg
```

In the above locations and files look like as below:

```
locations = ['ABC','XYZ']
files = ['file_1.txt','file_2.txt']
```

**Objective:**

I want the database records to be deleted based on conditions as listed in `location` and `files`

**My question is:**

Would the above approach work? Is there a better option available?

P.S.: I have not tried the above on DB directly as of now. Because the DB is in production and I have taken a dump and want to try the above on local DB.

Comment: For delete the record you have to use "DELETE FROM" instead of "DELETE * FROM"

Comment: Hey thats a typo...thanks for pointing out. Can you please do let me know whether the above for loops would work?

Comment: From code, I can understand that you want to delete the rows from table for given locations and files. If this is case, I will suggest you to use the simple DELETE with two IN clause. Let me know if you have this case. Or you want to perform some action on deleted rows? That will be useful to take decision.

Comment: I want to do this using Python. can you please be little more specific about what do you mean by IN clause?

Comment: I mean, I suggest you to use "DELETE" without loop. like... DELETE FROM ods.{} where location IN('ABC','XYZ') and filename IN ('file_1.txt','file_2.txt').